# Finding $Cov(X, Y)$ of $f_{X, Y}(x,y) ={\frac{1}{2}x^3e^{-xy-x}}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation, conditional-expectation

> $X$ and $Y$ have the following joint density:
>
> $$f_{X, Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases} {\frac{1}{2}x^3e^{-xy-x}}  & \text{$x
>  \gt 0, y \gt 0$} \\{0} & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
>
> (a) Give the value of $Cov(X, Y)$.
>
> (b) Give the value of $E(Y|X= 2)$

(a)

I asked this a few days ago but I made significant changes to my solution based on feedback I got. I think I have most of it right but am having difficulty calculating $f_Y(y)$. Wolfram Alpha and other online calculators do not give an output.

I have the following: $$Cov(X,Y)=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$$

$$E(XY)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} xy\frac{1}{2}x^3e^{-xy-x} dydx = 1$$

$$f_Y(y)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{2}x^3e^{-xy-x} dx = ?$$

$$f_X(x)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{2}x^3e^{-xy-x} dy = \frac{1}{2}e^{-x}x^2$$

$$E(Y)=\int_0^{\infty} y\cdot f_Y(y)dy=?$$

$$E(X) = \int_0^{\infty} x\cdot f_X(x) dx = 3$$

(b)

$$f_{Y|X}(y|x)=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}=\frac{x\cdot e^{-xy-x}}{e^{-x}}$$

Then $$E(Y|X=2)=\int_0^{\infty} y\cdot \frac{2\cdot e^{-2y-2}}{e^{-2}}dy=\frac{1}{2}$$

**Edit for part (a)**

$$E(Y)=\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} y\cdot\frac{1}{2}x^3 e^{-xy-x}dydx =0.5$$

Giving $$Cov(X,Y)=1-(3)\cdot(0.5)=-0.5$$

Is that right?

Comment: You don't need to find $f_{X}$ or $f_{Y}$. Just integrate $\int xf_{X,Y}$ and $\int yf_{X,Y}$ like you do with $\operatorname{E}(XY)$

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that!

Comment: You'll probably need to integrate by parts 3 times. That $x^3$ factor is not friendly.

Comment: I still integrate with respect to $x$ for finding $f_Y(y)$, correct?

Comment: Oh it's a double integral actually, right?

Comment: That's true, but the order of integration doesn't really matter if you're just finding expected values. You could also write the exponential as $e^{-x(y+1)} $ with $y+1$ being constant. Up to you

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I have it now. I have edited my question.

Comment: @Remy I have got the same result.